# Lower bound for sum of reciprocal of primes

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

In page 70 of the book *Approximate formulas for some functions of prime numbers* by J. Barkley Rosser and Lowell Schoenfeld, it is given that

\begin{equation}
\log\log x < \sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p}\quad \text{for}\, x>1
\end{equation}

How can one prove it? Is there an elementary proof of this? No proof has been mentioned in the book.

Comment: Formatting note: you posts will look nicer and be easier to read if you use `\log`, `\sin` and so on for common functions and operators.

Comment: The inequality you are asking about appears on page 70 as a *Corollary* to Theorem 5. Beginning on page 83, there is a section headed "Proof of Theorems 5 through 8," and on page 87 there is a paragraph that begins "We now proceed to the proof of Theorem 5." I found all this at https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255631807

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can argue as follows. A truncation of the Euler product gives

$$\prod_{p \le x} \left( \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{p}} \right) > \sum_{n=1}^x \frac{1}{n} = H_x > \log x$$

(since the LHS is exactly the sum of $\frac{1}{n}$ over all $n$ whose prime factors are $\le x$). Taking logs gives

$$\sum_{p \le x} - \log \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \right) > \log H_x > \log \log x$$

(all logs are natural). Taylor's theorem with remainder on the interval $[0, \frac 1 2]$ gives that if $0 \le x \le \frac 1 2$ then

$$\frac{x^2}{4} \le \log (1 - x) + x \le x^2$$

so $\log (1 - x) \le -x + x^2$ (we only need this half of the bound) on $[0, \frac 1 2]$ which gives

$$\sum_{p \le x} \left( \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^2} \right) \ge \sum_{p \le x} - \log \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \right) > \log \log x.$$

Since $\sum_{p \le x} \frac{1}{p^2} < \sum_p \frac{1}{p^2} < \sum_n \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ this gives

$$\sum_{p \le x} \frac{1}{p} > \log \log x - \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

which is not quite as good as what you asked for but pretty good; this argument requires no particularly hard tools. A slightly better version of this bound is given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes#Proof_that_the_series_exhibits_log-log_growth) but it doesn't get the constant all the way down to zero. There are several places in this argument where the bounds can be tightened up.

Comment: Thanks for your proof. Would the proof of the exact inequality be nonelementary?

Comment: @mathguy: I don't know.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan You should start off saying this is not an answer.